# How can I copy a file from one partition to another?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, 12.10, bootloader

I started with Linux a year ago. Few weeks ago it was my idea to install the  EFISTUB bootloader.

I used an Live CD to freshly install 12.10, and studied the articles of http://www.rodsbooks.com/ inside out.

The problem I am facing is that few files need to be copied from sda2 (Ext) to sda1 (fat32). I can not find a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean, "my esp having fat32"?

Comment: Sorry, Efi System Partition. In order to make efi work, a first partition is needed in Fat32.

Answer (score 0):

boot to live cd and use the mount command to mount both partitions,
then copy the files like normal.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/drv2
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/drv2

sudo mkdir /mnt/drv1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/drv1
```

Comment: If the drive with the partitions is connected to your system, it shouldn't require a Live Cd. Simply mount both partitions and copy the files as you'd like. Note that you may have to copy the files as Sudo if you don't have permissions with the files.

Comment: Also, if the system is already installed in EFI mode, there's a good chance that the ESP is already mounted at `/boot/efi`. Your kernel will already be accessible under `/boot`, of course. The different filesystem types are unimportant; user-level tools like cp just see files, not the details of the filesystems (ext3fs vs. FAT, for instance).

Comment: CD not needed:  Actually I used the CD to boot the machine to install the stubloader, which requires files to be moved from /boot to boot/efi.

Comment: I used gparted for making the gpt (rodsbooks.com) and a 500 mb fat32 sda1. So far so good. I installed Ubuntu on the second partition (sda2 - root), and /home on a third partition. Because I used a GPT partition table, I thought my MBR would be destroyed, consequently I thus had use the Installation cd. As I could not make it work, I eventually reinstalled Ubuntu, yet now using "EFI start-up partition" as an option during install (in stead of leaving it blank). As a result Ubuntu started from the HD, but used grub - very instable.

Comment: The issue, what are the commans to copy the files?  cp /boot/vmlinuz/ /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz.efi..?